# Unable to get phone number from contact list... code inside

Tags: android

Im new to android and programming in general (im a linux sys admin / scripting person).  And Ive been trying to get a simple android app going to get a feel for programming but I am having some problems.

I was able to string together some ideas and queries to get a list view of all the contacts,  but now id like to be able to grab the phone number of the selected contact but I am not having any luck...  I know there is probably better ways to do what I am doing but Im just trying to get a grasp on this.

Code first:

```
package com.SomeApp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
//import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class CallAppActivity extends ListActivity 
{  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  private ListAdapter mAdapter;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Get All information from ContactsContract
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(
      ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
      null, 
      null, 
      null, 
      null
    );

    //Activity will manage the cursor lifecycle.
    startManagingCursor(managedCursor);
    String[] columns = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    int[] names = new int[] {R.id.contact_entry};
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
      this, 
      R.layout.main, 
      managedCursor, 
      columns, 
      names
   );
   setListAdapter(mAdapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
  { super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor lookup = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position); 
    String contactId = lookup.getString(
      lookup.getColumnIndex(
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
      )
    );

    Cursor phone_num = getContentResolver().query(
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
      null, 
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, 
      null, 
      null
    );

    String phoneId = phone_num.getString(
      phone_num.getColumnIndex(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
      )
    );

    //We are going to print shit to a message box....
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertbox.setMessage(phoneId);
    alertbox.show();
  }
}
```

And now the logcat....

```
07-23 11:35:34.469: WARN/dalvikvm(781): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-23 11:35:34.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 11:35:34.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

No matter what Contact I pick I get the same exception,  So I obviously am doing something wrong.. I just cant quite figure it out on my own :(

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to make cursor pointer point to the first row to its data like `cursor.moveToFirst()` before you access data inside it? Actually, for `Cursor phone_num` and `Cursor phone_id`?

Comment: I sure did not,  but I just added it and low and behold it works now  I appreciate the quick response Nikola.  Can someone give me a quick explanation why that is needed?  Doesnt quite make sense to me why it is needed when I already have a query that should only return that value??

Comment: It is essential to put cursors pointer to the first record, so you can iterate through the records using .moveToNext() and checking if the that pointer is after the last record usin .isAfterLast(). Query does not returns only that value (better said one value) it returns as much as there is data to the conditions of the query respectively. You can use the cursors to iterate and see the results of the query. I hope my suggestion for your problem did the job and this quick explanation make things clearer for you. Cheers.

Comment: Nikola,  I appreciate the explanation your replies have been great help.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. If this answer was the solution, dont forget to accept it.